# Getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import com.apple.util.ConnectionPool;
import com.apple.util.DataSource;

public class AppResult {

    public void totalStatus(String appName) {
        ConnectionPool connectionPool;
        try {
            connectionPool = new ConnectionPool("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
                    "jdbc:oraclexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", “xxxxxabcowner", “xxxxx",
                    5, 10, true);
            DataSource ds = DataSource.getInstace();
            Connection conn = connectionPool.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) tot_app_name, sum(case when Status = 'UP'   then 1 else 0 end) status_up_count, sum(case when Status = 'DOWN' then 1 else 0 end) status_down_count from Application_Status;");
            System.out.println(stmt);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                
                int tot_apps = rs.getInt("tot_app_name");

                int tot_up = rs.getInt("status_up_count");

                int tot_down = rs.getInt("status_down_count");

                System.out.printf("tot_app_name = %s , status_up_count = %s, status_down_count = %s ", tot_apps, tot_up,tot_down);

                System.out.println(tot_apps);
                System.out.println(tot_up);
                System.out.println(tot_down);
                
            }
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
            connectionPool.free(conn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      AppResult hs = new AppResult();
      hs.totalStatus("App_Name");
      
      }
     
}

Getting this exception:-

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
    at com.apple.dao.AppResult.totalStatus(AppResult.java:22)
    at com.apple.dao.AppResult.main(AppResult.java:51)
```

I am trying to fetch the total no of apps, total no of up and down data from database using database connection pooling and stored into some variables like tot_app_name, tot_up, tot_down in java but getting this exception.If I will use simple database connection configuration ,still getting the same exception. How can I get fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, remove the trailing semicolon from your sentence, I think it is very likely the problem:

```java
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) tot_app_name, sum(case when Status = 'UP'   then 1 else 0 end) status_up_count, sum(case when Status = 'DOWN' then 1 else 0 end) status_down_count from Application_Status");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing "as" between column and column alias.

```
("select count(*) as tot_app_name, sum(case when Status = 'UP' then 1 else 0 end) as status_up_count, sum(case when Status = 'DOWN' then 1 else 0 end) as status_down_count from Application_Status;");
```